# store css file in user system untill client close my website

Tags: html, css, client

I am using `bootstrap.min.css` and my entire website uses this single CSS file for all pages. There are 179 pages on my website and my `bootstrap.min.css` is just 117Kb

- is there any way to store this file on the client's system when he opens home page
- and when user moves to the next page how can I use CSS file stored on the client's system ?
  [image: here is the tree view]

  this how am linking file this right method

  `<link href="../../../css/proper align.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the css file is accessed via the exactly same URL (same server, same path, same filename, no attached parameters) and the caching headers are set properly (which they are by default), the file will be cached by the browser.

You can check this behavior using the development tools of your browser.

Here you have a screenshot from the devtools of Google Chrome (hit F12). On the network tab I have selected `bootstrap.min.css` and I see that it is served from the browsers cache. All fine here. If you don't get it from cache, you can check the caching settings inside the response header.

[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmNhp.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

By default the .css file will get cached on client side.
This means it will only be downloaded once for all the 179 pages you have on you website.
All of this caching and reading from cache is handled by the client browser.
If you are not planning on doing any weird "magic" with the css file you won't have to worry about it.

If you reference the same path in the html file the browser will "know" that it has to use the already cached file.

This cache will most of the time persist after the client closes the browser and returns to your website a later time.

Comment: how do i use cached css file in other page

Comment: That is something you don't have to worry about.  The browser does this for you. If for example you use: href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" make sure you reference that file in all files and it will always work for you

Answer (score 1):

Well, the file IS stored on the clients system, it's called caching and is done automatically by browsers. If you reference the same file on all pages, then it's loaded from the same location.

If you worry about bandwidth, I recommend using a CDN-service for your Bootstrap file.
(eg. "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css")

Comment: how do i start CND-service

Comment: Instead of referencing the local css file, reference to the service =>
**<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">**